# Type assignment in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I don't understand why, in Typescript, I have this error in a varibale assignement; I think types are compatible, isn't it?
To work, I have to add:

```
async () => {
  dataFiles = <Array<DataFileLoadingInstructionType>>await Promise.all(
```

but why?
The error:

Type
'(DataFile | { file_path: string; header_line: number; sheets: never[]; type: string; })[]'
is not assignable to type
'({ file_path: string; } & { file_info?: string | undefined; file_name_suffix?: string | undefined; command_parameters?: string[] | undefined; } & { type: "unknown"; })[]'.

This is my the index.ts example:

```
import { DataFileLoadingInstructionType } from "./types_async";
import * as path from "path";

type DataFile = {
  file_path: string;
  type: "unknown";
};

const originalDataFiles: Array<DataFile> = [];
originalDataFiles.push({ file_path: "myFile.txt", type: "unknown" });

let dataFiles: Array<DataFileLoadingInstructionType>;

async function convertPathIfLocal(dataFile: string) {
  if (dataFile.indexOf("://") === -1 && !path.isAbsolute(dataFile)) {
    dataFile = path.join("my_dir/", dataFile);
  }
  return dataFile;
}

(async () => {
//here, I have to add <Array<DataFileLoadingInstructionType>> to work
  dataFiles = await Promise.all(
    originalDataFiles
      .filter((f) => f !== undefined)
      .map(async (dataFile) => {
        if (typeof dataFile === "string") {
          return {
            file_path: await convertPathIfLocal(dataFile),
            header_line: 0,
            sheets: [],
            type: "csv",
          };
        } else {
          dataFile.file_path = await convertPathIfLocal(dataFile.file_path);
          return dataFile;
        }
      })
  );

  console.log(
    `OUTPUT: ${JSON.stringify(
      dataFiles
    )} - type of dataFiles: ${typeof dataFiles}`
  );
})();
```

And this is my the types.ts example:

```
import {
  Array,
  Literal,
  Number,
  Partial as RTPartial,
  Record,
  Static,
  String,
  Union,
} from "runtypes";



const UnknownDataFileLoadingInstructionTypeOptions = Record({
  type: Literal("unknown"),
});

export const DataFileLoadingInstructionType = Record({ file_path: String })
  .And(
    RTPartial({
      file_info: String,
      file_name_suffix: String,
      command_parameters: Array(String),
    })
  )
  .And(Union(UnknownDataFileLoadingInstructionTypeOptions));

export type DataFileLoadingInstructionType = Static<
  typeof DataFileLoadingInstructionType
>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read of these code snippets, types are actually not assignable.

On one hand, `dataFiles` is declared with the type `Array<DataFileLoadingInstructionType>`, in other words:

```js
declare const dataFiles: Array<
  | { file_path: string, file_info?: string, file_name_suffix?: string, command_parameters?: string[] }
  | { type: 'unknown' }
>
```

On the other hand, the returned value of `originalDataFiles.filter(...).map(...)` is either:

```js
{
  file_path: string   // await convertPathIfLocal(dataFile)
  header_line: number // 0
  sheets: never[]     // [] inferred as Array<never>
  type: string        // "csv"
}
```

(cf. the returned object from the `if` branch, inside the `map`)

Or:

```js
DataFile
```

(cf. the returned object from the `else` branch, inside the `map`)

So, we end up with:

- `dataFiles` type:

  ```js
  Array<
     | { file_path: string, file_info?: string, file_name_suffix?: string, command_parameters?: string[]}
     | { type: 'unknown' }
  >
  ```
- `await Promise.all(originalDataFiles.filter(...).map(...))` type:

  ```js
  Array<
     | { file_path: string, header_line: number, sheets: never[], type: string }
     | DataFile
  >
  ```

And they are both, indeed, not assignable:

- The properties `header_line`, `sheets` and `type` are missing on the type `DataFileLoadingInstructionType`
- The property `file_path` is present in `DataFile` but not in `UnknownDataFileLoadingInstructionTypeOptions`

I'd say you should:

- Add the 3 properties to the `DataFileLoadingInstructionType`, otherwise adapt the returned object in the`if` branch of the `map` to make it compatible with `DataFileLoadingInstructionType`.
- Remove the property `file_path` from the `dataFile` returned in the `else` branch of the `map`,  or add the `file_path` property to the `UnknownDataFileLoadingInstructionTypeOptions` type.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the problem lies in misunderstanding string literals, the limitations of type inferencing and duck typing. That is quite a lot, but I will try to explain it bit by bit.

### Duck Typing

*"If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck."*

One of the nice things in Typescript that you do not need to instantiate a class in order for it to adhere to an interface.

```
interface Bird {
   featherCount: number
}

class Duck implements Bird {
    featherCount: number;
    constructor(featherInHundreds: number){
        this.featherCount = featherInHundreds * 100;
    }
}

function AddFeathers(d1: Bird, d2: Bird) {
   return d1.featherCount + d2.featherCount;
}

// The objects just need to have the same structure as the
// expected object. There is no need to have 
AddFeathers(new Duck(2), {featherCount: 200});
```

This creates a lot of flexibility in the language. Flexibility you are using in the `map` function. You either create an entirely new object where you adjust some things or you adjust the existing `dataFile`. In this case that might easily be solved by creating a constructor or method that returns a new class. If there are a lot of transformations this might lead to very large classes.

### Type Inferencing

However this flexibility comes at a cost in certain cases. Typescript needs to be able to infer the type, but in this case that goes wrong. When you create the new object, the `type` property is perceived as a `string` not the template literal `"unknown"`. This exposes two problems in your code.

1. The `type` property can only contain a single value `"unknown"` because it is typed as a string literal with just one value as opposed to a union of multiple literals. The type should at least have the type of `"unknown" | "csv"` for this value to work. However I expect that this is just a problem in this example since adding the `<Array<DataFileLoadingInstructionType>>` seems to solve the problem for you, while in this example it would break the example.
2. But even if you would adjust this or pass the only allowed value `"unknown"` here it would still complain. This is how Typescript infers types, since you just assign a value here, it presumes that it is the more generic string as opposed to the more narrow literal `"csv"`.

### Solution

The trick is helping Typescript type the object you are creating. My suggestion would be to assert the type of the property `type`, so that Typescript knows that the string assignment is actually a string literal.

**Example**

```
import {
    Literal,
    Number,
    Partial as RTPartial,
    Record,
    Static,
    String,
    Union,
} from "runtypes";
import * as path from "path";

// Create separate type, so that we don't need to assert the type inline.
type FileTypes = "unknown" | "csv"

const UnknownDataFileLoadingInstructionTypeOptions = Record({
    type: Literal<FileTypes>("unknown"),
});

export const DataFileLoadingInstructionType = Record({ file_path: String })
    .And(
        RTPartial({
            file_info: String,
            file_name_suffix: String,
            // Threw an error, commented it out for now.
            // command_parameters: Array(String),
        })
    )
    .And(Union(UnknownDataFileLoadingInstructionTypeOptions));

export type DataFileLoadingInstructionType = Static<
    typeof DataFileLoadingInstructionType
>;



type DataFile = {
    file_path: string;
    type: FileTypes;
};

const originalDataFiles: Array<DataFile> = [];
originalDataFiles.push({ file_path: "myFile.txt", type: "unknown" });

let dataFiles: Array<DataFileLoadingInstructionType>;

async function convertPathIfLocal(dataFile: string) {
    if (dataFile.indexOf("://") === -1 && !path.isAbsolute(dataFile)) {
        dataFile = path.join("my_dir/", dataFile);
    }
    return dataFile;
}

(async () => {
    //here, I have to add <Array<DataFileLoadingInstructionType>> to work
    dataFiles = await Promise.all(
        originalDataFiles
            .filter((f) => f !== undefined)
            .map(async (dataFile) => {
                if (typeof dataFile === "string") {
                    return {
                        file_path: await convertPathIfLocal(dataFile),
                        header_line: 0,
                        sheets: [],
                        type: "csv" as FileTypes,
                    };
                } else {
                    dataFile.file_path = await convertPathIfLocal(dataFile.file_path);
                    return dataFile;
                }
            })
    );

    console.log(
        `OUTPUT: ${JSON.stringify(
            dataFiles
        )} - type of dataFiles: ${typeof dataFiles}`
    );
})();
```